URLSession with URLSessionConfiguration.background configuration doesn't work when the app goes into the background on the device
My app plays audio files by first downloading them and then playing them. I am using URLSessionConfiguration.background to download the files, and it works fine in the foreground. However, when the app goes into the background, the downloading stops until it returns to the foreground. This issue occurs only on the device, while it works fine in both the foreground and background on the simulator.

Enabled background modes: Background Processing and Background Fetch.

Extended the background task using UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask.
However, I still get the same result where downloading in the background on the device doesn't work.



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Background sessions aren't really intended for doing work in the background that needs to happen soon.  They're designed for doing low-priority downloads without caring when you'll get the result, and ensuring that eventually the download will finish, potentially hours or days later.  Those downloads have the lowest priority, and if tasks are created in the background, they are also automatically treated as discretionary.
You might be able to fix this issue just by setting shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = YES on the session, but I'm not sure.
But really, if you expect to need that content quickly (for playing back audio momentarily), I think that you should probably not be using a background session, because there's presumably no reason for downloading to continue if your app actually gets terminated by the OS.  Rather, use a normal foreground session and rely on the Background Modes entitlement to ensure that fetching is allowed to continue while the app is backgrounded.  I'm not certain of this, though.
Also, if you're in low data mode, background accesses will likely be throttled unless allowsConstrainedNetworkAccess is on.  Also, be sure allowsExpensiveNetworkAccess is on for a similar reason.

Yes I think the problem in background session and should I use foreground session as you said. Thanks.
